# There is auto smooth option in 4.1?

Tags: modeling, mesh

*Acting in advance: This post is about future version, Blender 4.1*

I used to use auto smooth:

[image]

But I can't find this option in 4.1. Where is it?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Auto smooth has been removed due to technical and performance problems:

https://projects.blender.org/blender/blender/pulls/108014

Now there are 2 ways to set sharp edges in Blender 4.1:

### Non-destructive:

You can add *Smooth by Angle* modifier:

[image]

### Destructive:

You can use *Shade Smooth by Angle* from context menu:

[image]

It will add sharp edges to mesh without adding modifier.

[image]

To remove sharp edges, use *Shade Smooth", and from *Adjust last operation* uncheck *"Keep sharp edges"*

[image]