gaps in mesh in render view? not in viewport shaded view
gaps in mesh assembly in render view in viewport

https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/143529/displacement-map-creates-gaps-on-the-corners-of-a-wall https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/166561/displacement-causing-detached-faces And before you ask https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/311478/there-is-auto-smooth-option-in-4-1
